# Does Scarif host any resort communities?

Tags: star-wars, rogue-one

The depiction of the planet Scarif in Rogue One: A Star Wars Story was as a lush, tropical locale.  However, I don't know much about this planet outside of what was shown in the movie.  It seems like if the Empire was going to pour money into developing a military installation, it wouldn't be too much extra work to throw together some recreational facilities for the on-planet staff.

Is there any mention in any of the secondary Star Wars sources about resorts on Scarif?

(My guess is that Imperial minions don't vacation extensively, nevertheless I could see some kind of Prora-like set-up working both aesthetically and in terms of capacity.)

Comment: Assuming Adamant and Valorum have read the novel Rogue One tie-in novel: "Catalyst" - any additional thoughts as to the potential of Scarrif being a Legacy locale?

Comment: @NKCampbell - There's really no good indication one way or the other. Scarif is pretty far out of the way, has zero indigenous population or anything of value other than a nice climate and lots of natural metals. I'd say *probably not*.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

According to the film's junior novelisation, the answer is no. The presence of so many soldiers and so much military materiel has ruined the ambience.

> Bodhi flew the cargo shuttle through the gate. As he did, he gazed
> down at the complex below, which sprawled across a cluster of dozens
> of tropical islands. **In other circumstances, Scarif might have been a
> wonderful place to take a vacation, but the presence of the Empire’s
> data repository there had long since changed all that.**
>
> The complex centered on a steely-gray tower called the Citadel, which
> spiked out of the main island. There were twenty-five different
> landing pads on nearby islands arranged in a loose circle around that,
> and a system of railspeeder lines connected them all to each other.
>
> <sub><sup>[Rogue One: A Star Wars Story - Junior Novelisation](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Rogue_One:_A_Star_Wars_Story_%E2%80%93_A_Junior_Novel)</sup></sub>

Comment: Bodhi might not have thought it was a wonderful place to take a vacation, but I would suggest that Tarkin’s opinion is probably more telling about how Imperials (the only people who *could* take a vacation there) actually see it.

Comment: @Adamant - You have to remember that Tarkin has a deeply dysfunctional attitude toward any sort of luxury. He's a modern day Spartan.

Comment: I completely agree, but I would think he’d have an accurate opinion of how the other Imperials see it.

Answer (score 20):

### No, but the Imperials see it that way

I can’t find any evidence that anything besides the citadel complex and shield gate was built on Scarif. Certainly the Empire wouldn’t want to have resorts for outsiders (since it would jeopardize security)

Many Imperials certainly treated it that way, though.

> Tarkin looked to the viewscreen and to Scarif: an ocean-drenched
> sphere of islands rich with rare metals, useful as a construction
> outpost and research incubator away from the Senate’s prying eyes. But
> Tarkin would not miss it. **Over the years, too many officers had
> treated it as a place for unofficial retirement; a tropical paradise
> where they could neglect their duty in comfort.** The loss of the
> Citadel and the planetary shield would be a pity—but no more than
> that.
>
> <sub>*Rogue One: A Star Wars Story*</sub>

As we can see from this quote, the Empire generally isn’t a fan of luxury for its personnel. This provides further evidence that there aren’t any resorts proper on Scarif, since the Empire wouldn’t want to have resorts for soldiers (since it would encourage slacking off).

Comment: Their commitment to life-work balance leaves to be desired.

Comment: @DVK-in-Florida - The Imperials in general, those who vacation there, or Tarkin?